# Starbound: Sudden extreme cold at low depths?

Tags: starbound

I was mining, and there was a point where if I go down a few blocks, I start losing heat rapidly:
[image: Rapidly losing heat underground!]
But if I go back up to the platform directly above it, my heat starts *regaining* rapidly.
[image: Rapidly regaining heat.]
What's going on? And does it have to do with that blue and gold thing next to the thermometer in the first screenshot?

Comment: For the record, the blue thermometer to the left indicates that it is cold/freezing.

Comment: do you mean to the right?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, my bad.

Comment: okay, thank you :) I thought it might be a portal :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Starbound, planets can have multiple biomes, both above the surface and below the surface. This means a planet can have up to 4 biomes... Or more, counting any special biomes that may pop up from time to time.

This means that your above-ground biome could be warm, and then underground would be freezing, even though it's using the same tileset (coloured dirt, type of cobblestone, etc.)

---

The reason it suddenly went from warm to cold is because in Starbound, biome transitions aren't smooth; they sudden. Basically, once you pass the biome borders, the new effect kicks in 100% and straight away.

**Note:** When spleunkering, the underground sometimes changes biomes several times. This is because underground biomes have several layers. *ie. Layer 200 to -9 is normal (above ground), layers -10 to -500 is freezing, then -501 to -2000 is normal, -2001 to -3000 is freezing and then -3001 to -4000 is magma rock; warm.*

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on making some snow infantry armor, so that should stop the cold from going too fast, right?

Comment: That's an excellent starting anti-cold armor.